Resume training in Pytorch using previous persistent_workers state
How to save and restore persistent_workers state of DataLoader in order to resume training from a saved checkpoint.
First, I followed the steps in this discussion, so that the results are reproducible with different num_workers.
using exact steps as here, which has worker_init_fn as follows:
def _init_fn(worker_id):
    # Not necessary since we will reinitialize the internal generator state of the worker at EVERY SAMPLE!
    pass

Here's seed function at the start:
def set_seed(seed):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    random.seed(seed)

    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
        torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)

    torch.backends.cudnn.enabled = True
    torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True

the save function of checkpoints for every epoch including the random generator states:
checkpoint = {
‘cpu_rng_state’: torch.get_rng_state(),
‘gpu_rng_state’: torch.cuda.get_rng_state(),
‘gpu_rng_state_all’:torch.cuda.get_rng_state_all(),
‘numpy_rng_state’: np.random.get_state(),
‘py_rng_state’: random.getstate()
}

And to resume training from specific epoch, I restore the random generator states from saved checkpoint of that epoch.
Now if I don’t use persistent_workers (i.e., persistent_workers = False):

If I run the train process again from scratch, I can successfully reproduce the same results with num_workers >=0 for all epochs.
And, I can successfully resume training and reproduce the same results for all epochs.

For example, the batches for epoch 6 are as follows, and if I used the checkpoint of epoch 5, I can successfully regenerate same batches for epoch 6 again:
batch: 0 tensor([502, 437, 150, 787, 320, 303, 154, 939,  68, 899, 657, 716,  85, 484,
        334, 443, 734,  91, 473, 324, 733, 235,  75, 885, 739, 249, 704, 588,
        563, 825, 516, 820, 110, 242, 266, 100, 384, 638, 212, 709, 785, 807,
        295, 514, 460, 702, 207, 458, 415, 304, 653,  62, 104, 756, 348, 486,
        221, 621, 754, 500, 456, 871, 333, 421])
batch: 1 tensor([913, 595, 386, 122,  64, 191, 428, 634, 679,  12, 206, 594, 214, 633,
        849, 468,  18, 699,  24,  21, 248, 190, 884, 343, 940, 239, 124, 627,
         43, 908, 536, 329, 654, 413, 332, 253, 390, 843, 316, 280, 385, 159,
        234, 414, 137, 722, 710, 900, 222, 480, 344, 795, 664, 775, 335, 707,
        746, 435, 326, 349, 815, 895, 289, 237])
batch: 2 tensor([944, 696, 678, 545, 455,  42, 891,   5, 463, 452,  59, 771, 128, 914,
        751, 854, 101, 158, 592, 498, 524,  27, 394, 600, 765, 446, 391, 691,
        625, 232, 923, 850, 184, 635,  95, 245, 540,  71,  29, 372, 649, 282,
        360,  23, 290, 828,  50, 802, 194, 220, 658, 227, 142, 178, 140,  66,
        596, 438,  10, 300, 697, 723, 816, 505])
batch: 3 tensor([389,  80, 862, 407, 598, 323, 430, 629, 669, 671, 844, 267, 681, 301,
        201, 713, 168, 752, 448, 434, 856,  48, 467, 809, 155, 138,  37, 931,
        781, 367,  44,  97, 271, 336,  96, 800, 476, 630, 404, 472, 770, 177,
        205, 400, 766,  51, 322, 614, 742, 661, 520, 538, 149, 492, 162, 879,
        575,  83, 924, 466, 925, 577, 706, 761])
batch: 4 tensor([509, 757, 318, 942, 327, 726,  53,  52, 417, 419, 792, 585, 909, 684,
        873,  72, 799, 130, 935, 687, 283, 576, 380, 859, 228, 258, 832, 203,
        427, 308, 405, 583, 915, 273, 406, 778, 624, 676, 321, 571, 515, 209,
        608, 296, 172, 623, 418, 535, 487, 773, 555, 294, 772, 257, 260, 474,
        744, 202, 560, 449, 721, 338, 462, 493])
batch: 5 tensor([587, 477, 930, 776, 928, 805, 113, 173, 783, 226, 156, 652, 672, 262,
        808,  88, 632, 408, 933, 864,  65, 481, 745, 453, 846, 837, 636, 760,
        397, 118, 817, 169, 798,  14, 233, 806, 167, 517, 708,  93, 701, 877,
        523,  41, 838, 693, 642, 645, 131, 340, 357,  61,   6, 920, 801, 215,
        852, 789, 298,  84, 762, 219, 244,  98])
batch: 6 tensor([567, 628, 910, 615, 160, 840, 606, 728, 532, 558,   1, 528, 170, 865,
        610, 875, 442, 412, 788, 119, 164, 204, 165, 650, 860, 839, 192, 395,
          8, 932, 579, 129, 715, 127, 355, 626, 512,   2, 265, 293, 365,  31,
        857, 279, 639, 847, 163, 714, 803, 106,  63, 123, 759, 291,  74, 224,
        116,  79, 562, 619, 197, 272, 315, 217])
batch: 7 tensor([496, 461, 252, 937, 182, 121, 906, 749, 926, 921, 522, 470,  58, 551,
        897, 550, 552, 901, 319, 581, 306, 425, 107, 758, 682, 231, 299,   4,
        667, 829, 465, 181, 543, 382, 368, 313, 274, 111, 114, 513, 675, 869,
        302, 175, 180, 422,  39, 236, 748, 902, 819, 683, 907, 874, 491, 286,
        292,  20, 786, 572, 582, 354, 673, 230])
batch: 8 tensor([861,  45,   7, 183, 620, 521, 518, 157, 882, 153, 651,  73, 105,  19,
        823, 694, 152, 375, 377, 325, 229, 918, 537, 525, 366, 370, 352,  60,
         87, 578, 459, 135, 396, 255, 905, 554, 238, 416, 584, 841, 929, 870,
          9, 903, 858, 179, 640, 717, 200, 855, 889, 501, 548, 794, 631, 393,
        264, 755, 102, 208, 677, 109, 269, 868])
batch: 9 tensor([893, 409, 740, 542, 188, 378, 818, 647, 309,  94, 330,  54, 161, 607,
        278, 549, 126, 791, 539,  70, 362, 225, 784,  82, 605,  11, 530, 736,
        351, 185, 186, 436, 254, 483, 941, 337, 410,  86, 790, 831,  49, 195,
        526, 494, 488, 388, 381, 281, 147, 256,  78, 432, 108, 738, 133,  56,
        464, 811, 132,  90, 342, 285, 547, 617])
batch: 10 tensor([193, 243, 613,  15,  55, 328, 622, 531, 705, 139, 569, 223, 917, 827,
        507, 743, 503, 890, 544, 363, 141, 927, 361, 812, 475, 504, 665, 218,
        392, 810, 145, 288,  77, 566, 490, 750, 506, 358, 305,  92, 144,  69,
        120,  16,  35, 268, 830, 814, 546, 731, 867, 574, 591, 712, 916,  89,
        747, 176, 166, 403, 519, 143, 735, 198])
batch: 11 tensor([ 67, 331, 314, 310, 660, 668, 440, 601, 287, 565, 373, 216, 590, 387,
        720, 646, 780, 251, 196, 724, 777, 727, 489, 533, 339, 604, 892, 559,
        779, 680, 350, 674, 698, 826, 457, 174, 247, 399, 383,  17, 637, 411,
        374, 876, 880, 125, 719, 666,  26, 482, 284, 922, 353, 782, 346, 497,
        347, 495, 115, 655, 199, 833, 804, 451])
batch: 12 tensor([836, 499, 508, 402, 848, 718, 602, 297, 312, 479, 842, 656, 376,  22,
        189, 511, 768, 753, 767, 904, 689, 834, 616,  46, 527, 580, 561, 863,
        529, 356, 589, 568, 146, 441, 700, 851, 662, 845, 433, 797, 423,  32,
        597, 510, 641, 364, 250, 764, 793,  28, 134, 359, 478, 741, 564, 429,
        609, 171, 835, 187, 612,  33, 711, 881])
batch: 13 tensor([936, 690, 737, 872, 866, 644,  36,  30, 136, 599, 469,  99, 894, 371,
        725, 618, 369, 643,   3, 573, 534, 240, 444, 553,  25, 898, 210, 938,
        695, 888, 593, 729, 445, 896, 431, 401,  34, 703, 883, 246, 485, 919,
        103, 241, 934, 570, 276, 878, 603,  13, 611, 148, 341, 541, 821, 277,
        685, 692, 263, 912,   0, 379,  81, 117])
batch: 14 tensor([824, 471,  47, 275, 556, 648, 450, 259, 686,  57, 822, 732, 670, 663,
        813, 730, 317, 426, 420,  76, 796,  38, 887, 151, 911, 439, 774, 586,
        270,  40, 447, 261, 943, 211, 424, 557, 307, 853, 659, 886, 763, 345,
        213, 454, 398, 769, 311, 688, 112])

Now, if I use persistent_workers (i.e., persistent_workers = True) the retrieved batches and consequently results are different between num_workers = 0 and num_workers >0:

num_workers = 0, where (persistent_workers = False) and num_workers >0 , where (persistent_workers = True) agrees only in
first epoch retrieved batches and result.
If I run the train process again from scratch, I can successfully reproduce the same results for num_workers > 0 for all epochs. and also for num_workers = 0.
And, I can successfully resume training and reproduce the same results for each of them.

I wonder what is missing? Do we have to store the workers state and then restore again, and how?

Is this a worker issue? If you are looking to reproduce the batch order, that would point to the sampler in the dataloader. My guess is non-persistent workers allow you to reproduce the RNG because the worker is terminated and recreated when you start a new epoch. The workers start after your epoch snapshot so you can reproduce the state exactly. Persistent workers carry over from epoch to epoch so each epoch starts with some existing state

Solution:
The problem described above, arises when persistent_workers = True and shuffle = True even if I seed randomness in def _init_fn(worker_id).
A solution that works in order to use persistent_workers = True and obtain a reproducible results for num_workers >= 0 whether starting train from scratch or in resume case:

Use a sampler (e.g., torch.utils.data.RandomSampler for your
dataset), and assign it to the dataloader sampler.
Since sampler option is mutually exclusive with shuffle, set
shuffle = False in the dataloader, samples will be shuffled by the torch.utils.data.RandomSampler.

